# ASp.NET MVC 5 Date colum with correct format dd/MM/yyyy

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I m using MVC 5 and requirement is as below:

My viewModel property as below:

```
public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
```

This is optional field so user can manually type date (dd/MM/yyyy) format or leave it blank. 
Requirement is in-case user enter the invalid date it should get checked on client side to validate that date is in valid format. If not then form should not get submitted.
I tried following but it does not work.

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

Tried regular expression but still does not work. or work partially ..e.g. shows date wrong in I enter sdkjshdkj but validate it if format is wrong or even if I enter 22.

I don't want to use Jquery Calendar

Answer (score 0):

Try to use in view `TextBoxFor` instead of `EditorFor`

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date, "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control" })
```